# Are there developer APIs to hook into the camera connection kit for the iPad?

Tags: camera, ipad

Does Apple offer any developer APIs for reading data from the camera connection kit? (either via USB or on a card thats plugged in?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, not at this moment at least.

Comment: Nothing has changed as far as I'm aware.